# Where not use any article?

Tags: articles

"My favourite definition of a feminist is one offered by Su" - Is it grammatically right or whether it should be - "My favourite definition of a feminist is the one offered by Su".If both are correct, pls explain the difference between the two and the meaning they imply.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are acceptable.

***The** one offered by Su* implies that Su gave only one definition of a feminist.

*One offered by Su* is one of many, but this one happens to be by Su (who may or may not have given others).

Comment: And "a one offered by Su" would be redundant — there are cases when articles are unnecessary, and one of those cases is when we have a quantifying word like "one", "two", "many", "few", or "all".